# How to add horizontal offset to centered objects using figure environment?

Tags: floats

I'm currently new to LaTeX and trying to write my first proper document - a lab report. For this, I need to add plots to my page. To do this I'm currently using mathplotlib in python and exporting to a .pgf file like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.use("pgf")
matplotlib.rcParams.update({
    "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",
    'font.family': 'serif',
    'text.usetex': True,
    'pgf.rcfonts': False,
})

data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")

# the specific names are only relevant to my specific data

data.plot(kind="line", x="Volym(HCl)", y="pH(HCl)", legend=True, marker="o",ylabel="pH")
plt.savefig(".\\images\\plots\\HCl.pgf")
```

i later incorporate this output file in my LaTeX document like this:

```
\begin{center}    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{center}
            \input{images/plots/HCl.pgf}      
        \end{center}
        \caption{HCl plot}
    \end{figure}
\end{center}
```

[image: LaTeX output]

as you can see in the above output the x-axis label is off center relative to the figure label since the image is not square. Is there any way to add a horizontal offset to fix this?

Comment: First, do you really need *two* `center` environments for your figure? Second, the caption is centered in your example. Do you mean that you want it centered while ignoring the $y$ axis legend? If so, LaTeX has no way to detect parts in the image, so you'll probably need to use something like `\hspace` to add on offset to the caption text.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Your question is not related to the LaTeX code but to the python code, since this is where the axis labels are generated.

This is a simple rectangular plot saved as `HC5.pgf` and imported later to a LaTeX document. To fit the text area it has been resized to `\textwidth`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data for plotting
t = np.arange(0.0, 20.0, 0.1)
s = 1 + 12*np.sin(0.1 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set(xlabel='Volym(HCl)', ylabel='pH(HCl)',   title='Simple plot')
ax.grid()

plt.savefig(".\\images\\plots\\HC5.pgf")

plt.show()
```

[image: a]

As you can see the xlabel generated (by `matplotlib`) is correctly centered with the plot.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\usepackage{showframe}% show the margin

\begin{document}
      
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\input{images/plots/HC5.pgf}}     
    \caption{HCl plot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

(Of course, assuming that `images` is a subdirectory of your working LaTeX directory)

```
Python 3.6.4

matplotlib 3.3.4
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the tips, but that gives me "LaTeX Error: unknown graphics extension .pgf". My guess would be that .pgf isn't a raster image, since it is searchable and vector based as far as I know. Is there maybe some option to the graphicx package i'm missing?

Comment: Yeah, but it's not a .pdf file. It outputs as a specifically a .pgf. I don't have a file called HCl.pdf

Comment: @Marcell Sorry for my misunderstanding :(. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I finally understand. Funnily enough, tuns out what I was looking for was the \hspace command. As I said, I'm still very new and simply didn't know that it existed and just found it today by perusing the LaTeX documentation. Thanks so much for your efforts and sorry for all the confuison.